# Kubernetes kube-proxy is running but the specified kubeconfig file cannot be found

Tags: kubernetes, kube-proxy

I want to set k8s `kube-proxy` config file permission for hardening purposes.

I'm wordering how the `kube-proxy` process can be running with the `--config` flag set to a path (`var/lib/kube-proxy/config.conf`) that can't be found...

In fact checking `kube-proxy` process gives this :

```
[centos@cpu-node0 ~]$ ps -ef | grep kube-proxy
root     20890 20872  0 Oct20 ?        00:19:23 /usr/local/bin/kube-proxy --config=/var/lib/kube-proxy/config.conf --hostname-override=cpu-node0
centos   55623 51112  0 14:44 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto kube-proxy
```

But the file `/var/lib/kube-proxy/config.conf` does not exist :

```
[centos@cpu-node0 ~]$ ll /var/lib/kube-proxy/config.conf
ls: cannot access /var/lib/kube-proxy/config.conf: No such file or directory
```

Why?

Comment: Seems to be an issue with your particular setup. I've just take a look at my kube-proxy pod and there the config param is pointing to `/var/lib/kubelet/kubeconfig` where a valid configuration is available.

Answer (score 5):

I am also facing issue on my setup ( 1.19)

```
[root@project1kubemaster ~]# kubectl version --short
Client Version: v1.19.3
Server Version: v1.19.3

[root@project1kubemaster ~]# ps -ef | grep kube-proxy
root      2103  2046  0 11:30 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/bin/kube-proxy --config=/var/lib/kube-proxy/config.conf --hostname-override=project1kubemaster

[root@project1kubemaster ~]# ll /var/lib/kube-proxy/config.conf
ls: cannot access /var/lib/kube-proxy/config.conf: No such file or directory
```

One more interesting thing is "kube-proxy" is also not found :

```
[root@project1kubemaster ~]# ls /usr/local/bin/kube-proxy
ls: cannot access /usr/local/bin/kube-proxy: No such file or directory
```

Above made me realize that kube-proxy binary is running inside kubeproxy container of that node

```
[root@project1kubemaster ~]# kubectl get pods -n kube-system -o wide | grep proxy
kube-proxy-ffbqr                             1/1     Running   0          27m   <IP>   project1kubeworker2   <none>           <none>
kube-proxy-r9pz9                             1/1     Running   0          29m   <IP>  project1kubemaster    <none>           <none>
kube-proxy-zcrtw                             1/1     Running   0          27m   <IP>   project1kubeworker1   <none>           <none>

[root@project1kubemaster ~]# kubectl exec -it kube-proxy-r9pz9 -n kube-system -- /bin/sh
#
#
# find / -name config.conf
/var/lib/kube-proxy/..2020_11_02_16_30_32.787002112/config.conf
/var/lib/kube-proxy/config.conf
```

In short , It seems like kube-proxy binary & config files are inside kube-proxy pod of that node and they are running inside that pod . One reason why it might show up ps -ef output of host can be due to that pod is using Pid Name space of the host . also we can see that parent pid of kube-proxy process is nothing but containerd of that respective container .

```
[root@project1kubemaster ~]# ps -ef | grep 2046
root      2046 16904  0 11:30 ?        00:00:00 containerd-shim -namespace moby -workdir /var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/c3e9bf6ecdcdd0f56d0c76711cea4cadd023cd6ef82bf8312311248a7b0501a4 -address /run/containerd/containerd.sock -containerd-binary /usr/bin/containerd -runtime-root /var/run/docker/runtime-runc
root      2103  2046  0 11:30 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/bin/kube-proxy --config=/var/lib/kube-proxy/config.conf --hostname-override=project1kubemaster
```

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely  @confused genius, the `kube-proxy` process and its config files reside inside the `kube-proxy` pod.

```
[centos@hp-gpu-node2 ~]$ ps -ef | grep proxy
root       807     1  0 Oct20 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/gssproxy -D
root     12256 12239  0 Oct20 ?        00:18:42 /usr/local/bin/kube-proxy --config=/var/lib/kube-proxy/config.conf --hostname-override=hp-gpu-node2
centos   15338 10073  0 22:01 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto proxy
[centos@hp-gpu-node2 ~]$ ps -ef | grep 12239
root     12239  4681  0 Oct20 ?        00:00:37 containerd-shim -namespace moby -workdir /var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/415bc97a940caf1493db295d4b794e7313a431c6189d775d6e66a1337e13802f -address /run/containerd/containerd.sock -containerd-binary /usr/bin/containerd -runtime-root /var/run/docker/runtime-runc
root     12256 12239  0 Oct20 ?        00:18:42 /usr/local/bin/kube-proxy --config=/var/lib/kube-proxy/config.conf --hostname-override=hp-gpu-node2
centos   15452 10073  0 22:01 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto 12239
[centos@hp-gpu-node2 ~]$
```

Now list containers and get `kube-proxy` container short id :

```
[centos@hp-gpu-node2 ~]$ sudo docker container ls
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
b4ef8516ffba        nvidia/k8s-device-plugin                   "nvidia-device-plugin"   13 days ago         Up 13 days                              k8s_nvidia-device-plugin-ctr_nvidia-device-plugin-daemonset-1.12-k2jsn_kube-system_5eb15b43-12ce-11eb-a793-566f15970179_0
5361f340e00c        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.1   "/pause"                 13 days ago         Up 13 days                              k8s_POD_nvidia-device-plugin-daemonset-1.12-k2jsn_kube-system_5eb15b43-12ce-11eb-a793-566f15970179_0
415bc97a940c        gcr.io/google-containers/kube-proxy        "/usr/local/bin/kube…"   13 days ago         Up 13 days                              k8s_kube-proxy_kube-proxy-4d4hl_kube-system_3ebe3bf6-12cd-11eb-a793-566f15970179_0
762943484b1e        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.1   "/pause"                 13 days ago         Up 13 days                              k8s_POD_kube-proxy-4d4hl_kube-system_3ebe3bf6-12cd-11eb-a793-566f15970179_0
4bfdabe6597c        k8s.gcr.io/k8s-dns-node-cache              "/node-cache -locali…"   13 days ago         Up 13 days                              k8s_node-cache_nodelocaldns-hpvpb_kube-system_0c398cf7-12cd-11eb-a793-566f15970179_0
52c0f95f2d4c        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.1   "/pause"                 13 days ago         Up 13 days                              k8s_POD_nodelocaldns-hpvpb_kube-system_0c398cf7-12cd-11eb-a793-566f15970179_0
a34ec37154a8        calico/node                                "start_runit"            13 days ago         Up 13 days                              k8s_calico-node_calico-node-6vrn4_kube-system_fb95886a-12cc-11eb-a793-566f15970179_0
09895989f5b7        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.1   "/pause"                 13 days ago         Up 13 days                              k8s_POD_calico-node-6vrn4_kube-system_fb95886a-12cc-11eb-a793-566f15970179_0
eee5cc5a8e7a        53f3fd8007f7                               "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   13 days ago         Up 13 days                              k8s_nginx-proxy_nginx-proxy-hp-gpu-node2_kube-system_b853c9cd2cc0a3a71070731d4f6cfbca_0
d59e91a314a2        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.1   "/pause"                 13 days ago         Up 13 days                              k8s_POD_nginx-proxy-hp-gpu-node2_kube-system_b853c9cd2cc0a3a71070731d4f6cfbca_0
[centos@hp-gpu-node2 ~]$
```

Check `kube-proxy` config file permissions :

```
[centos@hp-gpu-node2 ~]$ sudo docker exec -t -i 415bc97a940 stat -c %a  /var/lib/kube-proxy/config.conf
777
[centos@hp-gpu-node2 ~]$
```

Answer (score 1):

For `kube-proxy` by default configuration file is volume mounted in the form of `configMap` to /var/lib/kube-proxy/kubeconfig.conf.

```
    ➜  ~ kubectl describe daemonset kube-proxy -n kube-system
    Name:           kube-proxy
    Selector:       k8s-app=kube-proxy
    Node-Selector:  kubernetes.io/os=linux
    Labels:         k8s-app=kube-proxy
    Annotations:    deprecated.daemonset.template.generation: 1
    Desired Number of Nodes Scheduled: 2
    Current Number of Nodes Scheduled: 2
    Number of Nodes Scheduled with Up-to-date Pods: 2
    Number of Nodes Scheduled with Available Pods: 2
    Number of Nodes Misscheduled: 0
    Pods Status:  2 Running / 0 Waiting / 0 Succeeded / 0 Failed
    Pod Template:
      Labels:           k8s-app=kube-proxy
      Service Account:  kube-proxy
      Containers:
       kube-proxy:
        Image:      registry.k8s.io/kube-proxy:v1.28.2
        Port:       <none>
        Host Port:  <none>
        Command:
          /usr/local/bin/kube-proxy
          --config=/var/lib/kube-proxy/config.conf
          --hostname-override=$(NODE_NAME)
        Environment:
          NODE_NAME:   (v1:spec.nodeName)
        Mounts:
          /lib/modules from lib-modules (ro)
          /run/xtables.lock from xtables-lock (rw)
          /var/lib/kube-proxy from kube-proxy (rw)
      Volumes:
       kube-proxy:
        Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
        Name:      kube-proxy
        Optional:  false
       xtables-lock:
        Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
        Path:          /run/xtables.lock
        HostPathType:  FileOrCreate
       lib-modules:
        Type:               HostPath (bare host directory volume)
        Path:               /lib/modules
        HostPathType:
      Priority Class Name:  system-node-critical
    Events:                 <none>
```

If you check `configMap` that mounted to `kube-proxy` it will look like this :

```
➜  ~ kubectl describe configmap kube-proxy -n kube-system
Name:         kube-proxy
Namespace:    kube-system
Labels:       app=kube-proxy
Annotations:  kubeadm.kubernetes.io/component-config.hash: sha256:2294f8ea53531bb5c20e91dc4a8571b9ac47abd2c5ec99e58ce4d7b115418fdd
Data
====
config.conf:
----
apiVersion: kubeproxy.config.k8s.io/v1alpha1
bindAddress: 0.0.0.0
bindAddressHardFail: false
clientConnection:
  acceptContentTypes: ""
  burst: 0
  contentType: ""
  kubeconfig: /var/lib/kube-proxy/kubeconfig.conf
  qps: 0
clusterCIDR: ""
configSyncPeriod: 0s
conntrack:
  maxPerCore: null
  min: null
  tcpCloseWaitTimeout: null
  tcpEstablishedTimeout: null
detectLocal:
  bridgeInterface: ""
  interfaceNamePrefix: ""
detectLocalMode: ""
enableProfiling: false
healthzBindAddress: ""
hostnameOverride: ""
iptables:
  localhostNodePorts: null
  masqueradeAll: false
  masqueradeBit: null
  minSyncPeriod: 0s
  syncPeriod: 0s
ipvs:
  excludeCIDRs: null
  minSyncPeriod: 0s
  scheduler: ""
  strictARP: false
  syncPeriod: 0s
  tcpFinTimeout: 0s
  tcpTimeout: 0s
  udpTimeout: 0s
kind: KubeProxyConfiguration
logging:
  flushFrequency: 0
  options:
    json:
      infoBufferSize: "0"
  verbosity: 0
metricsBindAddress: ""
mode: ""
nodePortAddresses: null
oomScoreAdj: null
portRange: ""
showHiddenMetricsForVersion: ""
winkernel:
  enableDSR: false
  forwardHealthCheckVip: false
  networkName: ""
  rootHnsEndpointName: ""
  sourceVip: ""
kubeconfig.conf:
----
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
    server: https://k8smaster.example.net:6443
  name: default
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: default
    namespace: default
    user: default
  name: default
current-context: default
users:
- name: default
  user:
    tokenFile: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token

BinaryData
====

Events:  <none>
```

If you want to check the contents of the configMap in kube-proxy you need to exec into the pod and extract file information.

```
➜  ~ kubectl exec kube-proxy-dmw6q -n kube-system -it -- /bin/cat /var/lib/kube-proxy/kubeconfig.conf
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
    server: https://k8smaster.example.net:6443
  name: default
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: default
    namespace: default
    user: default
  name: default
current-context: default
users:
- name: default
  user:
    tokenFile: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
```